# MapBox GL JS Query Feature Geometry Units

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

In MapBox GL JS, when I call *queryRenderedFeatures* or *querySourceFeatures*, it returns an array of features with geometries. Using a vector tile source, the feature geometry objects have coordinates like (-154.34, 80.99) for a location near the lat/lon (-77.37, 38.98). In what projection are the coordinates? And is there a way to convert them to WGS84?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, this is a MapBox bug. I added a bug report here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4011.

The geometry objects are supposed to have GeoJson lat/lons.